# How can I stop the IntelliJ icon in the dock from bouncing, without turning off bouncing for all applications

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

Use case on a Mac: you type a variable name into IntelliJ, and switch to the Java API to find out what you need to do. IntelliJ detects a compile error and starts bouncing its icon in the dock. Over and over. IT WILL NEVER STOP!

Does anyone out there have a solution that does not involve:

1. Turning off all bouncing in the dock
2. Turning off automatic syntax checking/compilation in IntelliJ

Comment: You're kind of hamstringing your options here.  You either don't show the bouncing or you don't have the inspection checker on constantly...I'm not 100% sure what other options you might have.

Comment: To be more precise: I want other applications to bounce, but not IntelliJ, in any situation if that's easiest.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7071

Answer (score 57):

Invoke `Find Action` from the Help menu (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and search for `Registry` in the popup that appears. Disable the `ide.appIcon.requestAttention` option in the Registry dialog (you can type in the dialog to search for this key). Be careful with the other configuration options, because it is possible to break your IntelliJ IDEA installation with an incorrect setting.

Comment: For Mac, the shortcut is Cmd-Opt-Shift-/

Comment: Works with PhpStorm as well. Thank you! That continues bouncing was sooooo anoying!

Comment: The shortcut does not work on a German keyboard. An alternative way is to type 'cmd + shift + A' and then type 'registry'.

Comment: Might be good to specify the version(s) of MacOS this worked for. Neither shortcut does anything for me on Catalina.

Comment: @ron-hd Perhaps you have configured an alternative keymap in IntelliJ IDEA? I have updated my answer with an alternative way to access the registry using the mouse.