# Turn Off IntelliJ "Compilation Finished" Notifications Under OSX

Tags: intellij-idea, notifications

Title says it all, really. They're annoying, I switch a lot between apps so any compilation started in intellij seems to cause the popup and sound to appear when done if switched out. Tried searching for notifications in preferences, tried clicking check mark off for ballon notifications, but that seems to be 'not it'.

Comment: BTW This seems related, but different problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642107/how-can-i-stop-the-intellij-icon-in-the-dock-from-bouncing-without-turning-off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA uses OSX's built in notifications to notify the compilation is finished. You can modify or disable them (also for any other application that displays notifications) in `System settings > Notifications` in the "Apple" menu.